# Why isn't core data maintaining persistance in this code?

Tags: ios, core-data, persistence

this is my code

```
+(FavouritesModel *) saveFavourites: (NSString *) title and: (NSString *) subtitle{

FavouritesModel *saveData = [[FavouritesModel alloc] init];
saveData.context = [saveData managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *task = [[Favourites alloc] initWithContext:saveData.context];

[task setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
[task setValue:subtitle forKey:@"subtitle"];

NSString *titleStr = [task valueForKey:@"title"];
NSString *subtitleStr = [task valueForKey:@"subtitle"];

[saveData.favouritesData addObject:titleStr];
[saveData.favouritesData addObject:subtitleStr];

AppDelegate *appDelegate;
[appDelegate saveContext];

return saveData;
}
```

The data I want saved but it's not persisting. I've used the saveContext() method in "applicationWillTerminate" in app delegate too. Still if I'm quitting and reopening the app, the data is not there.

**EDIT**
I'm using model class to call the method in 5 classes.

What do I have to add to implement data persistence ?

Comment: Can you just checkout your database? there must be entry once you save your coredata entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on the second of these lines

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate;
[appDelegate saveContext]; // <----- here
```

appDelegate is not being set correctly and the breakpoint will confirm this.

It needs to be set [something] like this:

```
// untested
appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Adding the last line you told, did the job !! 
Because it was a class method I had to make the another AppDelegate object inside the method and I missed --- appdelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Thanks !